# Get List of latest stable files from FTP server

Tags: python, ftp, paramiko, file-transfer

I'm trying to get the list of files that are fully uploaded on the FTP server.
I have access to this FTP server where a 3rd party writes data and marker files every 15 minutes. Once the data file is completely uploaded then a marker file gets created. we know once this marker file is there that means data files are ready and we can download it. I'm looking for a way to efficiently approach this problem. I want to check every minute if there are any new stable files on FTP server, if there is then I'll download those files. one preferred way is see if the marker file is 2 minutes old then we are good to download marker file and corresponding data file.
I'm new with python and looking for help.
I have some code till I list out the files

```
import paramiko
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

FTP_HOST = 'host_address'
FTP_PORT = 21
FTP_USERNAME = 'username'
FTP_PASSWORD = 'password'
FTP_ROOT_PATH = 'path_to_dir'

def today():
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d')

def open_ftp_connection(ftp_host, ftp_port, ftp_username, ftp_password):
    """
    Opens ftp connection and returns connection object
    """
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    try:
        transport = paramiko.Transport(ftp_host, ftp_port)
    except Exception as e:
        return 'conn_error'
    try:
        transport.connect(username=ftp_username, password=ftp_password)
    except Exception as identifier:
        return 'auth_error'
    ftp_connection = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    return ftp_connection

def show_ftp_files_stat():
    ftp_connection = open_ftp_connection(FTP_HOST, int(FTP_PORT), FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD)
    full_ftp_path = FTP_ROOT_PATH + "/" + today()
    file_attr_list = ftp_connection.listdir_attr(full_ftp_path)
    print(file_attr_list)
    for file_attr in file_attr_list:
        print(file_attr.filename, file_attr.st_size, file_attr.st_mtime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_ftp_files_stat()
```

Sample file name
`org-reference-delta-quotes.REF.48C2.20200402.92.1.1.txt.gz`
Sample corresponding marker file name
`org-reference-delta-quotes.REF.48C2.20200402.92.note.txt.gz`

Comment: I think some of the approaches implemented in the article [Watch a Directory for Changes](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) might be useful.

Comment: @martineau Code that works for local files is not relevant for working with FTP (or actually SFTP).

Comment: @Harsh First, make it clear what protocol you are using. You write about FTP, but your code is for SFTP. Second, your question is way too broad. What specific part of your task for you have a problem with? Do you want to find out if the marker file exists and is "old" enough?

Comment: @Martin: I believe the first part titled "Poll the directory with os.listdir" is relatively portable and could probably easily be adapted to work with FTP — which was the main point, not using the Windows OS specific stuff that follows that.

Comment: @martineau You cannot use `os.listdir` (nor any other `os.*` function) for working with files on FTP or SFTP server.

Comment: @Martin: I _know_ tthat, but there's a `listdir` equivalent for FTP, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my use case with 2 min stable rule, if modified time is within 2 min of the current time, I consider them stable.

```
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from ftplib import FTP


FTP_HOST = 'host_address'
FTP_PORT = 21
FTP_USERNAME = 'username'
FTP_PASSWORD = 'password'
FTP_ROOT_PATH = 'path_to_dir'


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


def today():
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc), '%Y%m%d')


def current_utc_ts():
    return datetime.utcnow().timestamp()


def current_utc_ts_minus_120():
    return int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()) - 120


def yyyymmddhhmmss_string_epoch_ts(dt_string):
    return time.mktime(time.strptime(dt_string, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))


def get_ftp_connection(ftp_host, ftp_username, ftp_password):
    try:
        ftp = FTP(ftp_host, ftp_username, ftp_password)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logger.error(e)
        return 'conn_error'
    return ftp


def get_list_of_files(ftp_connection, date_to_process):
    full_ftp_path = FTP_ROOT_PATH + "/" + date_to_process + "/"
    ftp_connection.cwd(full_ftp_path)
    entries = list(ftp_connection.mlsd())
    entry_list = [line for line in entries if line[0].endswith('.gz') | line[0].endswith('.zip')]
    ftp_connection.quit()
    print('Total file count', len(entry_list))
    return entry_list


def parse_file_list_to_dict(entries):
    try:
        file_dict_list = []
        for line in entries:
            file_dict = dict({"file_name": line[0],
                              "server_timestamp": int(yyyymmddhhmmss_string_epoch_ts(line[1]['modify'])),
                              "server_date": line[0].split(".")[3])
            file_dict_list.append(file_dict)
    except IndexError as e:
        # Output expected IndexErrors.
        logging.exception(e)
    except Exception as exception:
        # Output unexpected Exceptions.
        logging.exception(exception, False)
    return file_dict_list


def get_stable_files_dict_list(dict_list):
    stable_list = list(filter(lambda d: d['server_timestamp'] < current_utc_ts_minus_120(), dict_list))
    print('stable file count: {}'.format(len(stable_list)))
    return stable_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ftp_connection = get_ftp_connection(FTP_HOST, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD)
    if ftp_connection == 'conn_error':
        logger.error('Failed to connect FTP Server!')
    else:
        file_list = get_list_of_files(ftp_connection, today())
        parse_file_list = parse_file_list_to_dict(file_list)
        stable_file_list = get_stable_files_dict_list(parse_file_list)
```